# What does it mean here that Indian character has tended to fatalism and quietism?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading 'The Wonder That Was India' by A.L.Basham. In chapter 1, Introduction the author has this to say,

> Many other ancient civilizations, such as those of the Greeks, Romans and Chinese, had to contend with hard winters, which encouraged sturdiness and resource. India, on the other hand, was blessed by a bounteous Nature, who demanded little of man in return for sustenance, but in her terrible anger could not be appeased by any human effort. **Hence, it has been suggested, the Indian character has tended to fatalism and quietism, accepting fortune and misfortune alike without complaint.**

Does the author indirectly mean to say that Indians are complacent and ignorant?

Comment: No, s/he means what the second half of the sentence says. Ignorance is not implied. Have you looked up _fatalism_?

Comment: A submissive attitude to situations is what fatalism means. My point is that it could be expected of people millennia ago, but does he mean here that be it any of nature’s event like earthquake or flood, that Indians accept and do nothing or *can do nothing* about it ?

Comment: No, the author is saying that *someone else* has made these suggestions. And fatalism does not mean you do nothing or can do nothing, but accept the situation without complaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation does not appear to be correct (I would not agree that that's what is being said).  There are a number of things all packed into the original sentence that all must be considered in order to properly understand it.  It's a bit unclear which ones you've already gotten and which ones you might not, so I'll go through all of them, just to be sure:

> it has been suggested

First, this says that the author himself is not saying or implying anything.  Somebody else has suggested this, and he is just reporting what they said.  Phrases like this are sometimes used as "[weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word)" to express the author's own opinion without actually saying that's what it is, but it is also quite possible that this really is a position held by other people which the author may not necessarily agree with.

> the Indian character

This says that the person is talking about a combination of traits that are distinct or fairly unique to Indian people in general, but that doesn't necessarily mean that all Indians share them.  There may be many people who don't follow this pattern, but the existence of the pattern in many people is seen as something that is distinctly "Indian" in nature.

> has tended to

They are not necessarily saying that all Indian people actually *are* fatalist or quietist, but simply that their tendencies share some qualities with those philosophies, or incorporate parts of them, or that those philosophies are more common than others.

> fatalism and quietism

This is not the same thing as "complacent" or "ignorant".  Complacency is the lack of desire to change things that can potentially be changed.  Fatalism is the belief that (many) things simply cannot be changed, no matter how hard one tries.  Quietism, in its apparent usage here, is about choosing not to complain or make a big deal about negative things that happen to onesself, believing that it is better to accept them quietly than to risk bothering other people.

Neither of those philosophies have anything to do with ignorance.

> accepting fortune and misfortune alike without complaint

This is actually a good summary of exactly what was being suggested, and it's right there in the same sentence:  The implication is that many (not necessarily all) Indian people have a tendency to accept both good and bad things without a lot of complaints.

As for any value judgements about whether that's a good or bad thing, or whether the described European traits or Indian traits are better or worse, the author doesn't make any claims (in this passage, at least).  That appears to be left for you, as a reader, to decide.

Comment: I know this is just the introduction to the discovery and ancient history of the country so such explanations could be a little to lot confusing at times. But thank you for explaining it so well. Sure am going to have plenty of questions, but I will utilize this information as I move forward.